# How can I edit the color of text once it has been warped?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

In Illustrator I have warped text in an envelope and I can't figure out how to modify the color.  Is this possible, if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose `Object > Envelope Distort > Edit Contents` from the menu.

Comment: there isn't this option for me in Illustrator CC, anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

When you are in edit mode (warped object selected) your top bar menu will change. The first icon on the left (edit envelop) should be active. Click the 2nd one (edit contents), that will allow you to change the object fill color or contour.

Answer (score -1):

In Illustrator CC you can:

**Choose object > Envelope Distort > Expand**

Comment: Hi Toriki94, welcome to GD.SE! I would advise not to expand the object because you will not be able to edit the text and the object that is transforming the text. Scott's answer is a non-destructive way of editing the text without expanding. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: thank you very much for this answer...it really works for me... the > choose object > envelope distort > expand.